# Force page scroll position to top at page refresh in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pageload, page-refresh

I am building a website which I am publishing with `div`s. When I refresh the page after it was scrolled to position X, then the page is loaded with the scroll position as X.

How can I force the page to be scrolled to the top on page refresh?

- What I can think of is of some JS or jQuery run as `onLoad()` function of the page to **SET** the pages scroll to top. But I don't know how I could do that.
- A better option would be if there is some property or something to have the page loaded with its scroll position as default (i.e. at the top) which will be kind of like *page load*, instead of *page refresh*.

Comment: Surprisingly, none of the solutions here worked for me, but this one did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11486546/470749

Comment: I came here because I want the opposite behavior of what @Moon is asking for. EMACS impatient-mode keeps sending my web browser to the top of the document when I type new text into a buffer. This is disorientating and I wish I could make EMACS impatent-mode stop doing that.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

You can do it using the [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) method on [DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: Does not work on Safari. But this -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/18633915/102133 does.

Answer (score 255):

For a simple *plain* JavaScript implementation:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: @Paul12_ - I just tested it on `Safari 11.0.3` and works okay for me, which one are you using?

Comment: This did not work for me. I had to return from the onbeforeload function to make it work.

Comment: @Iqbal -- what did you `return`?

Comment: This throws the following error in Chrome:    Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'scrollTo' on 'Window': parameter 1 ('options') is not an object.

Comment: @OGSean - could I have a look at the exact excerpt of the code you wrote? You can give me [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) link.

Comment: adding `document.querySelector('html').style.scrollBehavior = '';` may be necessary too. If it was set to `smooth`, it might not get to the top before the page reloads.

Comment: @OGSean - Try window instead of Window

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox

Comment: @LenkaPitonakova - can share the code you are using? works on my end...

Comment: @ProfNandaa strange, I just copy-pasted the one in the answer. I'm on a Mac if that helps.

Answer (score 39):

The answer here does not works for safari,
document.ready is often fired too early.

Ought to use the `beforeunload` event which prevent you form doing some `setTimeout`

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: Add after scroll function : $('html').text(''); ,so stroller will be reset

Comment: @Userpassword Don't you think $("html").remove() would be better ?

Answer (score 30):

Again, best answer is:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
};
```

(thats for non-jQuery, look up if you are searching for the JQ method)

EDIT: a little mistake its "onbeforunload" :)
Chrome and others browsers "remember" the last scroll position befor unloading, so if you set the value to 0,0 just before the unload of your page they will remember 0,0 and won't scroll back to where the scrollbar was :)

Comment: @Paul12_ Safari requires `document.documentElement.scrollTop` to work. I typically use both though.

Answer (score 30):

To reset window scroll back to top, `$(window).scrollTop(0)` in the beforeunload event does the tricks, however, I tested in Chrome 80 it will go back to the old location after the reload.

To prevent that, set the `history.scrollRestoration` to `"manual"`.

```
//Reset scroll top

history.scrollRestoration = "manual";

$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
      $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: This is the best response for me, works on Chrome/Linux

Comment: This was great. In multi-page case, just added the two  lines `history.scrollRestoration = "manual";` and `$(window).scrollTop(0);` to the js function right after I make the second page visible.

Answer (score 13):

The JS history API has the scrollRestoration property, which when set to manual, prevents the last scroll location on the page to be restored:

```
if (history.scrollRestoration) {
    history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
} else {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, you can even simply use the `history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';` oneliner if you're working on a project where you know the browser will support it.

Comment: Thanks, changing to one liner might make a difference if you are using SSR and window is not available.

Answer (score 11):

You can also try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

If you want to scroll at x position than you can change the value of 0 to x.

Answer (score 10):

Check the jQuery `.scrollTop()` function [here](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

It would look something like

```
$(document).load().scrollTop(0);
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `location.reload()`, simply use `location.href = location.href`. It will not scroll to the previous position as `location.reload()` does.

*Note: This will not reload if there is any # in the URL*

Answer (score 5):

```
<script> location.hash = (location.hash) ? location.hash : " "; </script>
```

Put the above script in `<head>` tag of your html. Not sure how single page apps behave! But sure works like charm in regular pages.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

did not work for me as google chrome would just scroll back down after the page finished loading.
What I used was

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    console.log(url);
    if( url.indexOf('#') < 0 ) {
        window.location.replace(url + "#");
    } else {
        window.location.replace(url);
    }
});
```

// This loads the page with a # at the end. So it will always load at the top.

Answer (score 4):

The answer here(scrolling in `$(document).ready`) doesn't work if there is a video in the page. In that case the page is scrolled after this event is fired, overriding our work.

Best answer should be:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that these CSS styles force the page to always scroll to top on reload/refresh:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can confirm that this works. Would love if someone could get an explanation but nevertheless, this should be 2nd highest answer (above all those very, very repetitive `.scrollTop(0)`s),

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the best way to do so:

```html
<script>
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  $('body').hide();
  $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **location.replace** instead of **location.reload**:

```
location.replace(location.href);
```

This way page will reload with scroll on top.

Comment: This seems to work, but I can't find documentation to explain why it works. If anyone has that, please share!

Answer (score 1):

you can use it it your html page to
as:

```
history.scrollRestoration = "manual";

$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain what your code is doing and why this works? Seems legit, but you will want to explain this more for other readers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The supercalifragilisticexpialidocious answer is:

add this at the top of your **js** file or **script tag**

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera

document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
```