# Prevent browser scroll on HTML5 History popstate

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, browser-history

Is it possible to prevent the default behaviour of scrolling the document when a popstate event occurs?

Our site uses jQuery animated scrolling and History.js, and state changes should scroll the user around to different areas of the page whether via pushstate or popstate. The trouble is the browser restores the scroll position of the previous state automatically when a popstate event occurs.

I've tried using a container element set to 100% width and height of the document and scrolling the content inside that container. The problem with that I've found is it doesn't seem to be nearly as smooth as scrolling the document; especially if using lots of css3 like box-shadows and gradients.

I've also tried storing the document's scroll position during a user initiated scroll and restoring it after the browser scrolls the page (on popstate). This works fine in Firefox 12 but in Chrome 19 there is a flicker due to the page being scrolled and restored. I assume this is to do with a delay between the scroll and the scroll event being fired (where the scroll position is restored).

Firefox scrolls the page (and fires the scroll event) before popstate fires and Chrome fires popstate first then scrolls the document.

All the sites I've seen that use the history API either use a solution similar to those above or just ignore the scroll position change when a user goes back/forward (e.g. GitHub).

Is it possible to prevent the document being scrolled at all on popstate events?

Comment: You might have some success with reading an element dimension (to force a page reflow) after setting the scroll position. e.g. `document.body.clientHeight` but I haven't seen it work in all browsers.

Comment: What if you manipulated the document's scroll function, that is where I would start at least. There is a solution for it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035331/prevent-automatic-browser-scroll-on-refresh

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
if ('scrollRestoration' in history) {
  history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
}
```

([Announced by Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/history-api-scroll-restoration) on September 2, 2015)

**Browser support:**

Chrome: supported (since 46)

Firefox: supported (since 46)

IE: not supported

Edge: supported (since 79)

Opera: supported (since 33)

Safari: supported

For more info, see [Browser compatibility on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Shorter: `history.scrollRestoration && history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';` or even `var sr = 'scrollRestoration'; history[sr] && history[sr] = 'manual';`

Answer (score 33):

This has been a [reported issue with the mozilla developer core for more than a year now](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=679458). Unfortunately, the ticket did not really progress. I think Chrome is the same: There is no reliable way to tackle the scroll position `onpopstate` via js, since it's native browser behaviour.

There is hope for the future though, if you look at the [HTML5 history spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html), which explicitly wishes for the scroll position to be represented on the state object:

> History objects represent their browsing context's session history as a flat list of session history entries. Each session history entry consists of a URL and optionally a state object, and may in addition have a title, a Document object, form data, a scroll position, and other information associated with it.

This, and if you read the comments on the mozilla ticket mentioned above, gives some indication that it is possible that in the near future scroll position will not be restored anymore `onpopstate`, at least for people using `pushState`.

Unfortunately, until then, the scroll position gets stored when `pushState` is used, and `replaceState` does not replace the scroll position. Otherwise, it would be fairly easy, and you could use `replaceState` to set the current Scroll position everytime the user has scrolled the page (with some cautious onscroll handler).

Also unfortunately, the HTML5 spec does not specify when exactly the `popstate` event has to be fired, it just says: «is fired in certain cases when navigating to a session history entry», which does not clearly say if it's before or after; if it was always before, a solution with handling the scroll event occuring after the popstate would be possible.

**Cancel the scroll event?**

Furthermore, it would also be easy, if the scroll event where cancelable, which it isn't. If it was, you could just cancel the first scroll event of a series (user scroll events are like lemmings, they come in dozens, whereas the scroll event fired by the history repositioning is a single one), and you would be fine.

**There's no solution for now**

As far as I see, the only thing I'd recommend for now is to wait for the HTML5 Spec to be fully implemented and to roll with the browser behaviour in this case, that means: animate the scrolling when the browser lets you do it, and let the browser reposition the page when there's a history event. **The only thing you can influence position-wise is that you use `pushState` when the page is positioned in a good way to go back to.** Any other solution is either bound to have bugs, or to be too browser-specific, or both.

Comment: The wording of the history spec is slightly different now. In addition if you scroll down and look at the documentation of pushState there is no mention of adding a scroll position. The spec is suggesting that the session history entry may contain a saved scroll position, but I'm not sure that means the web developer will be able to set it.

Answer (score 4):

You're going to have to use some kind of horrible browser sniffing here. For Firefox, I would go with your solution of storing the scroll position and restoring it.

I thought I had a good Webkit solution based on your description, but I just tried in Chrome 21, and it seems that Chrome scrolls first, then fires the popstate event, then fires the scroll event. But for reference, here's what I came up with:

```
function noScrollOnce(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', noScrollOnce);
}
window.onpopstate = function () {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', noScrollOnce);
};​
```

Black magic such as pretending the page is scrolling by moving an `absolute` positioned element is ruled out by the screen repainting speed too.

So I'm 99% sure that the answer is that you can't, and you're going to have to use one of the compromises you've mentioned in the question. Both browsers scroll before JavaScript knows anything about it, so JavaScript can only react after the event. The only difference is that Firefox doesn't paint the screen until after the Javascript has fired, which is why there's a workable solution in Firefox but not in WebKit.

Answer (score 3):

Now you can do

```
history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
```

and this should prevent browser scroll. This only works right now in Chrome 46 and above, but it seems that Firefox is planning to support it too

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use `position: fixed` and specify `top` equal to scroll position of page.

Here is an example:

```
$(window).on('popstate', function()
{
   $('.yourWrapAroundAllContent').css({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: -window.scrollY
   });

   requestAnimationFrame(function()
   {
      $('.yourWrapAroundAllContent').css({
         position: 'static',
         top: 0
      });          
   });
});
```

Yes, you instead receive flickering scrollbar, but it is less evil.

Answer (score 1):

The following fix should work in all browsers.

You can set scroll position to 0 on the unload event. You can read about this event here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload. Essentially, the unload event fires right before you leave the page.

By setting scrollPosition to 0 on unload means when you leave the page with a set pushState it sets scrollPosition to 0. When you return to this page by refreshing or pressing back it will not autoscroll.

```
//Listen for unload event. This is triggered when leaving the page.
//Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload
window.addEventListener('unload', function(e) {
    //set scroll position to the top of the page.
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting scrollRestoration to manual not worked for me, here is my solution.

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {
    var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        document.body.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    });
});
```

Comment: Rumor has it `document.body.scrollTop` is deprecated. This worked for me:
`document.documentElement.scrollTop`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a 'span' element somewhere at the top of the page and set focus to this on load. The browser will scroll to the focussed element. I understand that this is a workaround and focus on 'span' doesn't work in all browsers ( uhmmm.. Safari ). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have implemented on a site that wanted the scroll position to focus to a specific element when the poststate is fired (back button):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     if (window.history.pushState) {
        //if push supported - push current page onto stack:
        window.history.pushState(null, document.title, document.location.href);
    }

    //add handler:
    $(window).on('popstate', PopStateHandler);
}

//fires when the back button is pressed:
function PopStateHandler(e) {
    emnt= $('#elementID');
    window.scrollTo(0, emnt.position().top);
    alert('scrolling to position');
}
```

Tested and works in firefox.

Chrome will scroll to position but then repositions back to original place.

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, there is no real way to do it, only ugly hacky way. Removing the scroll event listener didn't work for me, so here's my ugly way to do it:

```
/// GLOBAL VARS ////////////////////////
var saveScrollPos = false;
var scrollPosSaved = window.pageYOffset;
////////////////////////////////////////

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    //// Go back with keyboard shortcuts ////
    $(window).keydown(function(e){
        var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;

        if((e.altKey && key == 37) || (e.altKey && key == 39) || key == 8)
        saveScrollPos = false;
    });
    /////////////////////////////////////////

    //// Go back with back button ////
    $("html").bind("mouseout",  function(){ saveScrollPos = false; });
    //////////////////////////////////

    $("html").bind("mousemove", function(){ saveScrollPos = true; });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if(saveScrollPos)
        scrollPosSaved = window.pageYOffset;
        else
        window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosSaved);
    });

});
```

It works in Chrome, FF and IE (it flashes the first time you go back in IE). Any improvement suggestions are welcome! Hope this helps.

Answer (score -5):

Might want to try this?

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  return false;
};
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Some events can't be prevented, and popstate is one of them.