# Prevent automatic browser scroll on refresh without hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser

Similar to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035331/prevent-automatic-browser-scroll-on-refresh) is there any way to prevent automatic scroll without a hash / anchor up top. The method described in that post revolves around checking if there is a hash.

Is there a way to know if the browser has a point to scroll to OR if the page is being refreshed or just visited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) could be helpful.

Just cache the current scroll-offset if the page is reloaded (listening to `beforeunload` or `unload`) and then restore it when the page loads:

```
var $window = $(window).on({
  beforeunload: function() {
    window.sessionStorage.scrollLeft = $window.scrollLeft()
    window.sessionStorage.scrollTop = $window.scrollTop()
  },
  load: function() {
    $window.scrollLeft(window.sessionStorage.scrollLeft)
    $window.scrollTop(window.sessionStorage.scrollTop)
  }
})
```