# window.onload and expected behavior

Tags: javascript

I have the following code on a page:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

My expected behavior was that every time the page was displayed it would make the page scroll to `0,0` (top left).  But this isn't true, it only does it if I "reload" the page.  For example if I go to the page it scrolls to the top, but if I navigate away and come back it does not work.  Somehow the onload is not being triggered.

Since I am just learning, I am assuming I am expecting something that is not true.  Can some shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a cross-browser onload event when clicking the back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/is-there-a-cross-browser-onload-event-when-clicking-the-back-button)

Comment: Hi, have you tried `document.onload = function () { setTimeout( function () { window.scrollTo(0, 0); }, 500 ); };` ? **See my anser below...**

Answer (score 0):

`window.onload` gets called once the browser has finished parsing(aka reading) the html. The browser only needs to parse the html once whenever you load the page, so it only ever gets called once.

If you want it to be called whenever you refocus the tab, you can use the `window.onfocus` property.

Comment: OK so that works if I leave the tab open and come back to it (good to know).  What I meant by navigate away was go to a different page on the same website inside the same tab.  So if I have the original window.onload snippet on my "contact" page, then go to the home page and back, it doesn't trigger (neither does window.onfocus).

Comment: That’s not the desired behavior. The OP is asking for an event triggered on both loading the page and _navigatng to the page by clicking the back button_.

Answer (score 0):

When you go back to a page already visited the browser scrolls the page to the point you were when you left the last time.

A `scrollTo` invoked at `window.onload` either is ignored or it is executed **before** the browser gets into the way and restores the scroll position.

This is intended to give the user a better browsing experience, actually this is what normally a user expects, expecially when navigating back to the page via the "back" button.

But, if you really want to, you can override the browser behaviour by letting some time pass after `onload` and before your code scrolls the page to `(0,0)`:

```
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout( function () {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, 500 );
};
```

This way `window.scrollTo` is "scheduled" to be executed 0.5 seconds after page is loaded.

...and will **succeed**.

See also [Prevent automatic browser scroll on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035331/prevent-automatic-browser-scroll-on-refresh)

---

**Note:** since `window.onload` fires when the **entire page** has loaded (included images, links, frames...) the event (and subsequent scroll to `(0,0`) may be excessively delayed or not fired at all (if a resource fails loading).

I suggest to use (or at least try) `document.onload` that fires when the page has been parsed, the DOM structure is ready and linked resources start loading.

Your code becomes:

```
document.onload = function () {
    setTimeout( function () {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, 500 );
};
```

Since this triggers very early if you have issues you may raise a little the delay value to `750` or `1000` milliseconds.

---

For your reference you may find useful: [window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload)

Comment: This is giving me the desired effect MOST of the time.  I suspect an outside script is taking longer than .5 seconds to load.  Is there a way to trigger this after a specific item (div, script, etc...) loads?

Comment: @Vonedaddy - see my edit to the answer. Hope this helps.