# Reset scroll position on page refresh, did't work on modern browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser, scroll-position

I'm trying to reset browser scroll position on refresh and apparently it didn't work or ain't possible with modern browsers, am I wrong?

The code:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
$('html, body').scrollTop($('#scroll-to-div-id-anchor').offset().top); });
```

Maybe I'm handling this incorrectly and there is another way to achieve that?

I tried all variations and possible options to this code, but it didn't work on Safari and Chrome (both on desktop and, especially - mobile).

Comment: You're trying to reset it to 0 or some specific value?

Comment: I’m trying to reset it to an anchor (div id) @SergChernata, but I also tried to reset to “0” as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want the page to move to a certain element on reload, the expected behavior is to move the page to that point once it has been loaded. If you tried to move the page before it has been loaded, you won't know where you have to scroll to and if you tried to move it on unload, it's not guaranteed that that point will be saved once it's reloaded.

You can probably save the scroll location to the [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) on unload and attempt to load the location onload, but in this case I would recommend just moving the page onload.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html, body').scrollTop($('#scroll-to-div-id-anchor').offset().top);
});
```

Comment: It won’t happen on load, because browser store final position (and restore it after reload) at the time user hit the reload button @Chase I

Comment: @AndrewK It should work just fine as long as you make sure to run the change after the document has been loaded. Can you include your HTML and an example of the implementation where this answer doesn't work?

Comment: This is exactly the point, it just didn’t, don’t know why, even on a “blank” test page, when reload is hit, position stays the same and not restore to original one as you can expect from the code (Safari/ Chrome). @Chase I, tested on a blank test page, I can add html later, on mobile now

Comment: Ok, sounds good. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035331/prevent-automatic-browser-scroll-on-refresh#answer-31246298) answer may also hold some merit, but I don't have the environment set up to do the testing.