# How to get the window to scroll all to left and top in JAVASCRIPT - no jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code below.  If I scroll all the way to the right and then reload the page, I expected (based on my javascript code) for the window to scroll all the way to the left. However this does not happen. Please can someone advise?

```
 <html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<style>

#_1{
border: 1px solid blue;
width:1500px;
height: 400px;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div id="_1"></div>

</body>

<script>
window.onload = function(){

window.scrollTo(0,0);

}

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [**Force page scroll position to top at page refresh in HTML**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664381/force-page-scroll-position-to-top-at-page-refresh-in-html)

Comment: It is not a duplicate because if you run the code for above it does not work

Comment: It's really strange, it shows the same problem as yours, any way you check  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486527/reload-browser-does-not-reset-page-to-top/11486546#11486546) it gives a solution.

Comment: If their code doesn't work for you, why would accept the answer with the same code?

Comment: @dave Please once you just visit here hope you find the solution [CLICK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144805/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-using-javascript-jquery?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may try this?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

**Or**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Hope that you like it :)

Comment: These are the same solutions provided at [**Force page scroll position to top at page refresh in HTML**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664381/force-page-scroll-position-to-top-at-page-refresh-in-html) wich is just an identical duplicate of this answer.

Comment: its which not wich bro :)