# Prevent scroll jump during refreshing a long HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

On refreshing a long HTML page, the scroll position is initialized to the top and then jumped to the last scroll position.

Is there a way to stop this scroll jump behavior on refresh and just initialize scroll position to last scroll position?

Comment: Question is, are you using native javascript or a library such like jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about use html5 localStorage function.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    localStorage.scrollX = window.scrollX;
    localStorage.scrollY = window.scrollY;
})
window.addEventListener('load',function () {
    window.scrollTo(localStorage.scrollX || 0, localStorage.scrollY || 0);
})
```

Check it on http://jsfiddle.net/g5NKG/10/show/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may need the .scrollTop() method from jQuery found [here](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

So:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

From link in comments, this also is a quick fix:

```
$(document).scrollTop(0);
```

Comment: last scroll position!

Comment: Yes, @TomChung, there are a few other options [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664381/html-force-page-scroll-position-to-top-at-page-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just default browser behavior? What you're describing sounds like all mayor browsers are already doing it like that.

Comment: Yes, browsers do not reset the page to the page's top unless you tell them when refreshed.