# Make mobile page always load at the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I have tried to get this to work and was unsuccessful. I just want to have my mobile page views load at the top. I have tried the following.

```
// Method 1:
$('body').scrollTop(0);

// Method 2:
document.body.scrollTop = 0;

// Method 3:
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

I tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664381/html-force-page-scroll-position-to-top-at-page-refresh) first and was unsuccessful.

I just want to always start at the top of the page when I click a link in mobile. I have no idea as to why none of these solutions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use also **vanilla JS** for it:

```
document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

or with **JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Try also

```
$('html,body').scrollTop(0);
```

Check this demo as well, might help 
https://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/v575uvyb/2/

Comment: Tried this too. When I refresh it goes to the top but when I click a link to a new page it doesn't.

Comment: Oh, so your issue it's when you click on a link and open a new tab/page it's not at the top?

Comment: I made another demo for you. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Hey I just checked the demo. It still doesn't go to the top on page change. I changed it to.$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0, scrollLeft: 0 }, 200, function(){
  $('html,body').clearQueue();
});

Comment: I know, I was testing the scroll and i left the variables. I commented it for you too :)

Comment: Still trying to make sense of it sorry.

Comment: It did work! Thank you. Adobe CQ was the issue. Their mobile emulator was making me think it was not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should include `$(this).scrollTop(0);` within a `$(document).ready();` call, [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3664409/604687):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

In your code, you are calling `$(this).scrollTop(0);` [before the page unloads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload), rather than [after the page and DOM have been reloaded](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: What happens instead? Are you sure the function is being called?

Comment: I am sure because the alert loads. When I scroll halfway down the page then click to go to a new page it stays at the same vertical position instead of starting at the top.

Comment: Are you loading new page content in to the same page via AJAX, or truly loading a new page?