# while reloading a page it automatically retaining the scroll position of page how it is happening?

Tags: javascript, html, reload

When a page is reloaded, it automatically retains the scroll position. How is it happening?

I need the page to scroll back to the top on each reload.

Comment: It might be because there is an anchor in the url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML - force page scroll position to top at page refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664381/html-force-page-scroll-position-to-top-at-page-refresh)

Comment: Your browser is probably doing it.  It happens in Chrome.

Comment: @YounesM if there is a anchor, will it maintains the scroll position ?

Comment: @Mahi yes on reload it will move to the anchor. But what Archer said is true, Chrome seems to keep track of scroll position on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your page between `<script>` tags:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

This will reset the scroll position when the page is about to unload.

Comment: Can I know how it automatically retaining in the scroll position ?

Comment: The browser, like Chrome, is built or coded this way: it will remember the position where you were before reloading.

Comment: As @ManuelCheța said, this is browser implementation specific and is done automatically. You have no control over it, but can work around it.