# Force Page to Return to top on Reload - Javascript

Tags: javascript, reload, onbeforeunload

I have a problem in vanilla JS that has been asked in slightly differing forms on this site, but there doesn't seem to be an answer for vanilla javascript? I would like the page to appear at the top on reload / refresh using vanilla JS (without any scrolling back up to the top with scrollTop()).

I've checked these questions and the related answers:

[Prevent automatic browser scroll on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035331/prevent-automatic-browser-scroll-on-refresh/18633915#18633915link)

[Force page scroll position to top at page refresh in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664381/force-page-scroll-position-to-top-at-page-refresh-in-html)

[Prevent automatic browser scroll on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035331/prevent-automatic-browser-scroll-on-refresh?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The problem is there are two vanilla JS answers scattered in these questions, one of which doesn't work in IE/Edge, the other one doesn't work in Safari

Doesn't work in Safari:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
};
```

Doesn't working in IE / Edge

```
history.scrollRestoration = "manual";
```

Surely there must a way of getting a page to appear at the top on refresh / reload?

Also I can't have it scroll up to the top on reload / refresh so any scrollTop() related answers aren't applicable.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can always just add some flags to include both solutions:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if(window.scrollTo) window.scrollTo(0,0);
};
```

and

```
if(history && history.scrollRestoration) history.scrollRestoration = "manual";
```

*Also I can't have it scroll up to the top on reload / refresh so any scrollTop() related answers aren't applicable.*

also why?

Comment: I can't have scrollTop() because there is a relatively complex animation that just looks silly as the page scrolls back up because you miss the start of it.  Also I can't use your answer because the `.onbeforeunload` property causes unwanted behaviour in Safari — the page scrolls down to the previous point after loading. Thanks for taking the time to answer though.

Comment: Which is why we add both solutions to compensate. Also you can call the line during `.onload`.