# How to set table scroll position on top

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, scrollbar

I'm working with Angular v11.1 and typescript v4.0.5, the problem is the following:

I have a [mat-table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) with a lot of rows, so I decided to put it into a div with `max-height=60vh` and `overflow:auto` to add a scroll bar for the table.

It works as expected until I refresh the website, when I do that, the table is reload in the same position I left it before and I want to reload it on top instead.
Any idea or advice of how to solve this?

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664381/force-page-scroll-position-to-top-at-page-refresh-in-html

Comment: I tryed that but it doesn't work.